# Simulation Using Pseudorandom Numbers and the Inversion Method

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, matlab

I am trying to do this problem to understand the statistics 
Could you please help me out?

Consider the distribution function of the so-called extreme value distribution with parameters a and b:

[image]
Implement a matlab function myev(a,b) that returns a single
pseudorandom number for this distribution on each call using the inversion method. Put down the mathematical considerations below on this printout.

b) Implement a simulation of the following scenario: values of myev(10,2) are used to draw samples of
the monthly maximum level of water in a hydropower station. If out of the 12 values describing a year’s
monthly maximum levels, at least 6 are smaller than the yearly mean value, this year is a “bad=0” one, otherwise, it is a “good=1” year. Implement a function simu() that simulates one year and classifies it
and outputs either 1 or 0.
c) Implement a script control() that outputs the percentage of “good” years. To do so, compute (below)
a sample size n of simulations such that the 95% confidence interval for this estimate is ±5%.

Comment: I have given a general answer focused on the 'inversion method', You will get a cheerier reception on this site if you show your work and say why what you have tried is not enough. In this particular case it might also be helpful to explain Matlab functions. \\ Matlab is wonderful commercial software, but it is sufficiently expensive that usage is largely restricted to those with access to university or commercial licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint about the theory (ignoring particulars of Matlab): My intent is to
review and illustrate the 'inversion' method without doing your Matlab homework.

Let $U = F(X) = \exp[-\exp(-\frac{X-a}{b})],$ and solve for $X$ in
terms of $U$ to obtain $X = F^{-1}(U).$ Then if $U \sim \mathsf{UNIF}(0,1),$
the corresponding $X$ is a random observation from the distribution
described by the CDF $F.$

As a closely-related example, you can use a random number generator
that produces standard uniform output $U$ to get realizations of 
$X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(1),$ which has CDF $F(x) = 1 - e^{-x},$ for $x > 0.$
Setting $U = F(X)$ gives $X = -\ln(1-U).$ [This is often simplified to
$X = -\ln U$ because both $U$ and $1-U$ are both standard uniform.]

In R statistical software, the following code simulates an $m$-vector of independent
realizations of $\mathsf{Exp}(1).$ [The function `runif`, without extra
arguments, generates the indicated number of standard uniform RVs. `log` is $\ln,$ and `dexp` is the exponential density function, where the second
argument is the rate parameter.]

```
m = 10^6;  u = runif(m);  x = -log(1 - u)
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
    main="Histogram of Simulated Dist'n of EXP(1) with Exact PDF")
curve(dexp(x, 1), lwd=2, col="red", add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I understand which confidence Interval I should use , a T-test or Normal ?

Comment: I don't see how that is related to your Question, but here goes: If you have data from a normal population of size $n$ and want a CI for the population mean $\mu,$ then you use a z-interval (normal interval) if the population standard deviation $\sigma$ in known, and you use a t-interval (based on Student's t distribution win $n-1$ degrees of freedom) if $\sigma$ is unknown (and thus estimated by $S$.)